# Quick sort: Pivot is the first element that is greater than its neighbor

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am learning quick sort and I found an algorithm where pivot is the first element that is greater than its neighbor, here is pseudo code

```
void quicksort(int i,int j)
{
    pivotindex=findpivot(i,j);
    if(pivotindex!=-1)
    {
        pivot=a[pivotindex];
        k=partition(i,j,pivot); // l
        quicksort(i,k-1);
        quicksort(k,j);
    }
}


int findpivot(int i, int j)
{
    for i=0 to j
    {
        if(a[i]>a[i+1])
        return(i);

    else if(a[i]<a[i+1])
        return(i+1);

    else
        continue;
    }
return(-1);
}


int partition(int i, int j, int pivot)
{
    int l, r;
    l=i, r=j;
    do
    {
    swap(a[l],a[r]);
    while(a[l]<pivot)
        l=l+1;
    while(a[r]>=pivot)
        r=r-1;
    } while(l<r);
    return(l);
}
```

Will this pseudocode work fine?

I tried to write c++ code for this, here is my code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void swap(int *i,int *j){
    int temp = *i;
    *i = *j;
    *j = temp;
}


int partition(int l, int r, int idx, int arr[]){
   
    do{
        int index = arr[idx];
        
        swap(&arr[l],&arr[r]);
        
        //cout<<arr[l]<<" "<<arr[r]<<" pivot : "<<index<<endl;
        
        while(arr[l]<index){
            l=l+1;
        }
        while(arr[r]>=index){
            r=r-1;
        }
        
        
    }while(l<r);
    
    return l;

    
}

int findpivot(int l,int r,int arr[]){
    
    for(int i = l; i<=r; i++){
        if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]){
            
            return i;
        } 
        else if(arr[i+1]>arr[i]){
            
            return i+1;
        } 
        else{
            continue;
        }
        
    }
    return(-1);
    
}


void Quicksort(int l, int r,int arr[]){
    
    int idx = findpivot(l,r,arr);

    
    
    if(idx!=-1){
        int pivot = arr[idx];
        
        int  k = partition(l,r,idx,arr);
       
        
        Quicksort(l,k-1,arr);
        Quicksort(k,r,arr);
       
    }

}





int main()
{
    int arr[10] = {19,23,11,43,24,68,98,47,99,89};
    Quicksort(0,9,arr);
    
    cout<<"final"<<endl;
    for(int i =0;i<10;i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

My code does fine till these steps and then it turns into an infinite loop, is something wrong with my code, or is the pseudocode wrong?
{89,23,11,43,24,68,98,47,99,19}

{19,23,11,43,24,68,98,47,99,89}

{19,11,23,43,24,68,98,47,99,89}

{11,19}

can someone help me with this.

Comment: First line of findpivot makes no sense: `for i=0 to j` since you lose i

Comment: `findpivot` does _not_ generally return the greatest element, if that was the intent - it will return the first element that is greater than its neighbor. Besides, using the minimum or maximum value as the pivot for Quicksort, is the _worst_ case, not the best.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what [@stark says in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69498437/quick-sort-pivot-is-the-first-element-that-is-greater-than-its-neighbor#comment122839988_69498437) about the initial value in the pseudocode's iteration in `findpivot`, the termination condition is clearly incorrect. Your implementation fixes the initial value (which was probably a typo) but repeats the problem with the termination: `for(int i = l; i<=r; i++)`.

But the termination condition must be `i < r`. If `i` is equal to `r`, the loop will access element `a[r+1]`, which is outside the range (and possibly outside the array). In addition, the algorithm depends on `findpivot` detecting the end-of-recursion condition, which is when all the elements in the range are equal, not when all the elements in the range *and the next element* are equal. Hence the endless loop.

Comment: I tried changing these but still, the loop doesn't end.

Comment: @AxXxelWolf: You don't mention what change you attempted, so I have no idea what you actually did. The change I suggested, which is to replace the condition `i <= r` with `i < r`, works perfectly for me.

Comment: I edited the answer to possibly make the suggested change more obvious.

Comment: I first changed ```i<r``` to ```i<= r``` and then I placed ```int index = arr[idx];``` outside do while loop, after these two changes the program worked fine. Thanks for the help.